# SSHD: Windows: dealing with swapfile

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, pagefile

So I've started thinking about buying SSHD (Solid State Hybrid Disk) disks for an older workstation which will never receive a memory above 16GB and is used extensively, so that a page file usage is constantly high.

8GB of SSD cache sounds like something that will wear out fast.

Now, the question: is there a way to make these SSHDs (currently I'm thinking of Seagate ST1000DX001) exclude a predefined area (for the page file) from being cached (both read/write, SLC/MLC)?

Comment: I see no reason you shouldn't use a swap on the hybrid disks, if the firmware does not handle this, then they are not worth even using.  The benefits you get out of using a swap outway the benfits of these hybrid disks.

Comment: Check out [SSD cache in SSHD compromises the lifecycle compared to standard HDD?](http://superuser.com/questions/581169/ssd-cache-in-sshd-compromises-the-lifecycle-compared-to-standard-hdd)

Comment: Your SSD elements are not going to wear out in the drive's expected lifetime. The mechanical part(s) of the drive are much more likely to fail before the cache starts failing.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I rolled back your edit, as SSHD's are a real thing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHD :)

Comment: SSHD has SSD part meant for caching and only that, do do not fear of NAND cells wearing out. Proper SSHD will have caching controlled by firmware, therefore swap file that can potentially harm cells life will be produced by OS on HDD part of the disk.